# Best way to implement RTL in Swift?

Tags: swift, right-to-left

I want to present my app in Arabic RTL language when user clicks on the Arabic in the language selector inside the app(default language is English). I have referred lot things, still I am unable to get perfect output. Anyone, please suggest me an best way to do this.

Comment: Just use autolayout, it will flip the aligment automatically

Comment: Are you change direction with alignments or just alignments?

Comment: I just change the alignments and do not change the direction(push, pop)

Comment: Is this one is correct for textfield?,
 if(language == "Arabic"){
            Phone.textAlignment = .right
        }
        else{
            Phone.textAlignment = .left
        }

So if Arabic people started editing they will get the sentence correctly?

Comment: Also, Is we want to change all the label text programatically? Or Is there any alternate way?